# MATLAB: Plotting 2 figures into 2 axes, in a GUI

Tags: matlab, plot, axes, figures

I have 2 figures generated that show a 3D cube, and one that shows a net. I have associate these with two axes in a GUI using this:

```
 axes(handles.cube);
 axes(handles.net);
```

What I do not understand is how to transfer the figure into each one.
This is probably very simple, I'm very new and very inept with this piece of software- so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean take the content of `handles.cube` and plot it in `handles.net`? Do you want both plots on the same graph basically?

Comment: No sorry I was quite vague. I have two separate figures that launch when I run my code, but rather than opening up into two figures in separate windows- I want to render them in the two axes that I have drawn in guide. What is the easiest way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: you can specify the axes in which you want to display your plot: `plot(YourAxes,x,y,...)` so you could use `handles.cube` and `handles.net` instead of `YourAxes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use subplot for plotting two different axes in one window, if this is what you desire:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/displaying-multiple-plots-in-a-single-figure.html